# Increasing bump value turns the specular shine into a halo shape?

Tags: texturing, materials, bump

I've been running into a problem where whenever I increase the bump the shiny specular goes into a halo shape, here's a gif to show it in action

(https://gfycat.com/thirstylimpinghackee.gif)

Comment: While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to 
questions they should not remain the only way to obtain information 
about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on 
downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools 
to [upload images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or 
[gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), besides 
thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be 
searched for and indexed thus helping future users find it.

Comment: Alright! Will make sure to do so next time

Comment: Cool, you can always *edit* your question btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At default settings, this:

[image]

is 1 **meter**.  To illustrate, here are a couple of cubes, one with *Bump* applied, and one with some *Subdivision* and *Displacement*.

[image]

In essence, *Bump* is perturbing the normal data to give the left cube the appearance of the right cube without adding any geometry.  That's probably not even anywhere close to the appearance you had in your head for this wall/window, and so you see something you don't like and can't quite explain in the viewport.

By lowering the *Strength* you are mitigating the issue, but not solving the root cause.  Instead, the *Distance* for this (imo) should be somewhere around .001 to .01, and that may be enough to solve it.

[image]

For reference, .0254 (2.54cm) is an inch, so when you're doing stuff like wood grain and stucco you're going to have really small values.  The image above got just a little destroyed by compression, but you can see that with the values scaled down the cubes retain similar appearances.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! ^^