# Normal Maps create very high lighting contrast under sunlight

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, normal-map, shader-nodes

I am new to Blender and I am currently working to understand materials. I am now trying to apply normal maps to add details which, correct me if I'm wrong, create a really nice and realistic "scattered" highlight effect. However, with HDRI lighting implemented and under certain camera angle, the light and shadow contrast is somehow exaggerated creating a very hard and defined  shadow line. I changed to the displacement modifier and the shadow seems more or less reasonable, but I am on a rather low-end PC and it can only afford a 10 subdiv, so I cannot be certain about that. Please could anyone tell me if this is how things are supposed to be, physically speaking? Thanks for any help.
This is what happens with normal maps applied
[image]This is the render result with the original principled shader
[image: this is the render result with the original principled shader]

This is the result from the displacement
[image]

And this is my node setup, as you can see, it is really just a normal map, and I have already set the color space to non-color.[image] The hdri I use is the "urban street 04" from hdri haven and the texture is "Fabric 039" from cc0 textures, both in 2k resolution. Links below:
https://polyhaven.com/a/urban_street_04
https://ambientcg.com/view?id=Fabric039

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/234846/110840

Comment: Displacement is a different thing, I wouldn't place your normal map there.

Comment: Oh by the word "change to displacement" I mean apply a displacement modifier with a displacement map, changing the geometry, that kind of thing. Sorry for my bad expression xD